# How to a manage a multi-target project using GIT in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, branch, target

We are working on a Xcode project that results in different apps on the AppStore. Each app has its own target and is developed in its own GIT branch. There is also a big chunk of code being shared among the targets (both in storyboards and viewcontrollers). So the question is what is the best way to manage the branches? Is it better to have all the branches merged into the master or it's better to have the shared chunk of the code in master and keep each target's code in its own branch as it is.

PS: There is always a chance of creating a new target for a new app from the master branch.

Comment: You can check this http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-branches-to-maintain-different-editions-of-the-same

Answer (score 0):

Use Master for everything, but when you make changes to something - spawn a new branch, and if the "shared code" is touched, then you have to be super careful about merges. A good way to do this is to keep a constant safety branch for the shared code going.

Comment: I don't quite understand how having a safety branch will help our situation. Additionally, what you are proposing is the conventional way of branching in git which we are already doing (i.e. having a base code and develop new features/apps in new branches).